# How to set selected value for multiple dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropdown, html-select

I'm populating multiple dropdowns with the same data.

How do I set the selected value from the array below for each iteration?

```
const arraylist = ['Tom', 'Joe', 'Bill'];
const iterable = ['Mark', 'Jill', 'Ben', 'John', 'Tom', 'Joe'];

let dropdown = '';
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    dropdown += "<select name='samedata' class='dropdownlist'>";
    for (const [index, v] of Object.entries(iterable)) {
        let checked = arraylist.includes(v) ? 'selected' : '';
        dropdown += `<option value="${v}" ${checked}>${v}</option>`;
    }
    dropdown += '</select>';
}
```

Where the first dropdown having `Tom` selected, second having `Joe` and the rest having nothing selected.

Comment: So, 5 dropdowns each with the same set of names, but the first having Tom sleected, the second having Joe selected and the rest having nothing selected?

Comment: They will all have Tom and Joe selected...

Comment: The only thing missing from your code is that the `select` needs the `multiple` attribute:  https://jsfiddle.net/0qcjv4z1/ as you want multiple values selected.

Comment: @Kinglish Exactly.

Comment: @Kinglish Can you show a working solution in resolving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add in some additional code to get it to work. First to check to see if a 'selected' option had been found for each `<select>` iteration and then an `array.splice()` to remove that option from the `arraylist` array.

```js
const arraylist = ['Tom', 'Joe', 'Bill'];
const iterable = ['Mark', 'Jill', 'Ben', 'John', 'Tom', 'Joe'];

let dropdown = '';
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let found = false;
  dropdown += "<select name='samedata' class='dropdownlist'><option></option>";
  for (const [index, v] of Object.entries(iterable)) {
    let checked = !found && arraylist.includes(v) ? 'selected' : '';
    if (!found && checked) {
      arraylist.splice(arraylist.indexOf(v), 1);
      found = true;
    }
    dropdown += `<option value="${v}" ${checked}>${v}</option>`;
  }
  dropdown += '</select>';
}
document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = dropdown
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Kinglish. Worked as expected.